# pyqtgraph: how to do not display time series before 00:00 time (using AxisItem)

Tags: python, datetime, time-series, pyside, pyqtgraph

how can I display time axis starting from 00:00 and do not display time axises before 00:00? Graph will display real time data read from sersor. And it will start plotting the data at the very right side of the graph starting from 00:00(time when data is arrived) and will slide to the left as data arrives. So I want to get rid of the time-axis values before 00:00?
I appreciate all your suggestions.

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from PySide.QtCore import QTime, QTimer
from collections import deque

t = QTime()
t.start()
data = deque()
class TimeAxisItem(pg.AxisItem):
def tickStrings(self, values, scale, spacing):
    return [QTime().addMSecs(value).toString('mm:ss') for value in values]

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
win = pg.GraphicsWindow()
win.resize(1000,600)
print type(win)
axis = TimeAxisItem('bottom')
plot = win.addPlot(title='Timed data',axisItems={'bottom':axis},enableMenu=False)
curve = plot.plot()

now = 0
timeStart = -15000
minX =-15000
i = 0
def update():
global i, plot, curve, data,minX,now,timeStart
time = t.elapsed()
data.append({'x': time, 'y': np.random.randint(0, 100)})
timeStart += 1
x = [item['x'] for item in data]
y = [item['y'] for item in data]
if i == 0:
            difference = x[-1]
            i = 1
else:
            difference = x[-1] - x[-2]
minX += difference
plot.setXRange(minX,x[-1])
curve.setData(x=x, y=y)
tmr = QTimer()
tmr.timeout.connect(update)
tmr.start(100)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
    QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just provide a blank string for anything less than 0?

```
def tickStrings(self, values, scale, spacing):
    return ['' if value < 0 else 
            QTime().addMSecs(value).toString('mm:ss') for value in values]
```